# Confusion over bisecting angles of asymptotic curves

Tags: differential-geometry

For E,F,G coefficients of the First Fundamental Form, and L,M,N of the Second, how do i show the following:

For $p \in S$ a regular surface, with Gauss curvature $\kappa(p) > 0$, show that the lines of curvature through $p$ bisect the asymptotic curves through $p$.

So far I have that a line of curvature implies $$(FN-GM)(v')^2 - (GL-EN)(u'v') + (EM-FL)(u')^2 = 0$$ and that for an asymptotic curve (as normal curvature $\kappa_n = 0$) $$\kappa_n = \frac{(u')^2L + 2u'v'M + (v')^2N}{(u')^2E + 2u'v'F + (v')^2G} = 0 \implies(u')^2L + 2u'v'M + (v')^2N = 0$$

Here is where I'm confused. Could you please explain how this could show that lines of curvature bisect asymptotic curves, and your thought process when checking this?

Comment: Have you learned Euler's formula for normal curvature? You can certainly use what you've written to find the angle between the asymptotic curves and one of the principal directions, but it's not enlightening. (Use the first fundamental form to find the dot product of the respective tangent vectors.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I haven't learned Euler's Formula for normal curvature, but after googling it I think I've seen it before. I don't understand how to use it to prove this though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What values of $\theta$ give $\kappa_n = 0$ if you apply Euler? But you can, as I said, use your formula. Solve for $dv/du$ for your asymptotic curve(s) (in terms of $L,M,N$. Do the same for the line(s) of curvature. Compute the inner product of the tangent vectors using the first fundamental form.

Comment: Having said that, I think the algebra is hopeless. If you're at an umbilic point, there is no asymptotic direction. Away from an umbilic point, you can parametrize so that the coordinate curves are lines of curvature.